# LocationListener inconsistently called

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to create my own location provider in android to inject my own positioning data in the system. To do that I'm reusing the LocationManager functions in the system, registering a listener there that I expect to be called, but it is not always called. I've done some research but I can't figure out the pattern that the system use to triggers the events, and there is not extensive official documentation from Google.

Please, note that I don't use any location provider from the system (GPS, network...). I create my own coordinates and timestamp and publish it in the fake location provider, so almost all the questions about this issue are slightly different from this one (so nothing to do with the GPS, whether if I am moving or not, the minimum distance parameter...).

Here I show you the code and the Log generated. You can easily see that some events are never triggered (like onProvider enabled), triggered when it shouldn't (onProviderDisbled) or triggered at wrong times (like onStatusChanged, only triggered if there after a status change AND a location change).

Here's the main code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!isMockLocationSet()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Mock Locations are disabled!");
        }

        // 1. Generate a valid random name for the mock provider
        providerName = this.generateValidProviderName();

        // 2. Create the mock provider
        System.out.println("Step 2: Create provider (" + providerName + ")");
        try {
            if (lm.getProvider(providerName) == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {// Doesn't exist, create
            lm.addTestProvider(providerName, false, false, false, false, false,
                    false, false, Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM, Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        }

        // 3. Register for updates
        System.out.println("Step 3: Register for updates");
        MyLocationListener l = new MyLocationListener();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 0, 0, l);

        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
        task.execute();

    }
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Location loc = new Location(providerName);

            // 4. Enable it!
            System.out.println("Step 4: Enable it");
            lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, true);

            // 5. Change the status
            System.out.println("Step 5: Change the status to AVAILABLE");
            lm.setTestProviderStatus(providerName, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                    null, System.currentTimeMillis());

            // 6. Change the status
            System.out
                    .println("Step 7: Change the status to TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE");
            lm.setTestProviderStatus(providerName,
                    LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE, null,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            // 7.1. Change location
            System.out.println("Step 7.1: Change Location");
            loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            loc.setLatitude(52.0f);
            loc.setLongitude(10.0f);
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);

            // 7.2. Change location
            System.out.println("Step 7.2: Change Location");
            loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            loc.setLatitude(52.1f);
            loc.setLongitude(10.1f);
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);

            // 7.3. Change the status
            System.out.println("Step 7.3: Change the status to AVAILABLE");
            lm.setTestProviderStatus(providerName, LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,
                    null, System.currentTimeMillis());

            // 7.4. Change location
            System.out.println("Step 7.4: Change Location");
            loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            loc.setLatitude(52.2f);
            loc.setLongitude(10.2f);
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);

            // 7.5. Change the status
            System.out.println("Step 7.5: Change the status to OUT_OF_SERVICE");
            lm.setTestProviderStatus(providerName,
                    LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE, null,
                    System.currentTimeMillis());

            // 7.6. Change location
            System.out.println("Step 7.6: Change Location");
            loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            loc.setLatitude(52.3f);
            loc.setLongitude(10.3f);
            lm.setTestProviderLocation(providerName, loc);

            try {
                // 8. Delete provider
                System.out.println("8. Delete provider");
                lm.setTestProviderEnabled(providerName, false);
                lm.removeTestProvider(providerName);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here the log's output:

```
07-26 11:31:21.271: I/System.out(8721): Step 2: Create provider (Fake_GPS_92A4)
07-26 11:31:21.271: I/System.out(8721): Step 3: Register for updates
07-26 11:31:21.276: I/System.out(8721): Step 4: Enable it
07-26 11:31:21.276: I/System.out(8721): Step 5: Change the status to AVAILABLE
07-26 11:31:21.276: I/System.out(8721): Step 7: Change the status to TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE
07-26 11:31:21.276: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.1: Change Location
07-26 11:31:21.291: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.2: Change Location
07-26 11:31:21.301: D/MainActivity(8721): onProviderDisabled
07-26 11:31:21.306: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.3: Change the status to AVAILABLE
07-26 11:31:21.306: I/System.out(8721): onLocationChanged 
07-26 11:31:21.306: D/MainActivity(8721): onStatusChanged: TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE
07-26 11:31:21.306: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.4: Change Location
07-26 11:31:21.306: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.5: Change the status to OUT_OF_SERVICE
07-26 11:31:21.356: I/System.out(8721): Step 7.6: Change Location
07-26 11:31:21.361: I/System.out(8721): 8. Delete provider
07-26 11:31:21.401: I/System.out(8721): onLocationChanged 
07-26 11:31:21.401: I/System.out(8721): onLocationChanged 
07-26 11:31:21.436: D/MainActivity(8721): onStatusChanged: AVAILABLE
```

Of course, it is not a permission issue:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

I've spent lot of time with that issue and simplified the code to the minimum expression, so I hope you could at least have a look.

Thanks!